# How do I get the URL and selection text from the Android browser with the share intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In new versions of Android phones (definitely starting in ICS, possibly as early as 2.3.5, at least on an HTC EVO) when you make a selection in the browser, it shows a popup which has 3 dots, clicking on that opens a menu that offers options to copy, share, etc.  If you choose share, you can select to share to an application.

For an application I'm working on, I need both the selected text and the URL of the page it came from when the user shares to my app.

On an HTC EVO running 2.3.5 this provides both the URL of the page as well as the selected text.  However on other phones we're only getting the selected text.  So I'm suspecting getting both on the HTC EVO was a carrier/manufacturer enhancement.  For this phone the selected text comes in as Intent.EXTRA_TEXT and the url in Intent.EXTRA_TITLE.

Anyone know a way to get both the selection text and URL .  If this is a carrier/manufacturer enhancement, any ideas how widespread it is?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that there is no reliable way to get a URL from a "text/plan" mime type share intent.  Browsers put the URL in EXTRA_TEXT, but other apps do not (e.g. FlipBoard).